# How to override an existing meta tag in html?

Tags: html, web-crawler, meta-tags

I have an html document with this meta tag :

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

I want to keep this tag in the head but override it with this new declaration :

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
```

Should i put the overriding tag before or after the first one ?

Comment: Why do you want to keep the first one?

Comment: I want to keep the first one because its included from a template used on 99% of the pages.

Comment: you can replace content using jquery $("meta[name='robots']").attr('content', 'noindex, nofollow');

Comment: Thanx but its not really the question. The question is : From my exemple which directive will be taken by the browser if two directive hold the same name : The first or the last ?

Comment: it will replace for those who have the same name  name="robots"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we consider only the *robots* meta tag:

***The best possible way will be to include ONLY the correct meta tag in the page output.***

---

There is no HTML convention to override meta tags, so the effect of having multiple conflicting meta tags will be interpreted differently by the the different services (browsers, search engines, etc.) using them.

In your case there is no guarantee how different search engines will follow your robots instructions. Some of them may use the first occurrence, others may used the last occurrence and Google may use the more restrictive instruction.

The last one was mentioned here [Official Google Blog Post](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2007/03/using-robots-meta-tag.html), but it's from 2007 and things may changed.

---

Although there is a way to change dynamically the content of meta tags with Jquery by using something like:

```
$("meta[name='robots']").attr('content', 'index, follow');
```

There is again no guarantee that this will take the desired effect. 
Google executes JavaScript when crawling your page (*I'm not sure it will respect this*), but other search engines may not.

*Additional information about Google executing JavaScript when crawling pages:*

- [Official Google Blog](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html)
- [Search Engine Land](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)

Comment: As per this answer, I'd say that it is best do include your `meta` tag through server side - check if it's the desire page and if it is, put `index, follow` , else put `noindex, nofollow`.

Comment: Changing such data via javascript is pretty pointless when search engine crawlers don't execute javascript.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider that's why I'm suggesting as the best solution that only the correct meta tag is included initially in the page output. By the way I included references to Google Official Blog and some independent tests that Google are executing JavaScript when crawling your page.